# How to convert two columns into a single string column with dynamic linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using [System.Linq.Dynamic](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic) to provide dynamic querying of a number of database sources (SQL server) and it all works really well, but now I've hit a snag. I need to be able to take two numeric columns and format them into a single string. Essentially what this boils down to is that I'm doing something like this (note, this isn't exactly what I'm doing because the whole thing is dynamic and the actually string passed to `Select` is built dynamically):

```
var mystuff = data.Select("year, qtr, string.Format(\"{0}Q{1}\",year,qtr) as yearQtr");
```

Surprisingly, `System.Linq.Dynamic` does actually appear to interpret this as I wanted, but unfortunately, it throws a `System.ArgumentException` error:

```
Expression of type 'System.Int16' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Object' 
of method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)'
```

I *think* the problem is that it's not boxing `fact.year` (which is of type `System.Int16`) automatically like it would when you normally use `string.Format`. So is there a way to tell it to box `year` and `qtr`?

I tried simply casting to `object`, but that doesn't work:

```
var mystuff = data.Select("year, qtr, string.Format(\"{0}Q{1}\",(object)year,(object)qtr) as yearQtr");

An exception of type 'System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException' occurred in JobsEQ.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: '.' or '(' expected
```

Apparently dynamic linq doesn't understand casting.

**Update**: It occurred to me to just `ToString()` them:

```
var mystuff = data.Select("year, qtr, string.Format(\"{0}Q{1}\",year.ToString(),qtr.ToString()) as yearQtr");
```

But now I get a different exception (`System.NotSupportedException`) that makes me think I'm heading down the wrong path:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

So is there another way to make it convert these two columns into a single string column?

Comment: Looks like string.format method was tied to execute in sql. Have you tried `year + 'Q' + qtr`(like you did in sql) instead of string.format?

Comment: @Reniuz: That actually gives me the same boxing problem: `Expression of type 'System.Int16' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Object' of method 'System.String Concat(System.Object, System.Object)'` and adding `ToString` leads to a similar `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String.Concat(...'`

Comment: Then last thing what I would try is to box integers with [SqlFunction.StringConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466276(v=vs.110).aspx) But still expecting similar string to object error :)

Comment: @Reniuz: Unfortunately, `"No property or field 'SqlFunction' exists in type '<>f__AnonymousType1e`3'"` even if I fully qualify the type, I then get `"No property or field 'System' exists in type '<>f__AnonymousType1e`3'"` It doesn't seem to recognize that this is a static method on another type.

Comment: So as I understood `years.ToString()` is valid line yes? And some problems occurred with `string.concat`. Then how about `string.Concat(year.ToString(), 'Q', qtr.ToString())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the string manipulation on the application side, rather than trying to do it on the database side of things.  As you can see, even though dynamic LINQ can create an expression tree to represent the call to `Format`, EF doesn't know how to translate it into SQL.

Instead simply ask the database for the columns that you need, and then perform the string transformations of those values on the application side using LINQ to objects.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking that might be my only choice, but it makes things really complicated because of the dynamic nature of the query. I need to make it a two step process and figure out how to distinguish fields that have to be selected *after* the database query from ones that can be selected *before*.

Comment: @MattBurland Trying to build such complex queries dynamically comes with costs.  LINQ is designed to be used with statically defined queries after all.

Comment: Understood. Just looking for the least fiddly way to do it.